# numpy reshaping the EEG data in channels and trials

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on Electroencephalogram dataset. Dataset is measured using 16 electrodes. Each subject data has an array of shape 122880 data points. Channel 1 measure 7680 data points, channel 2 measure 7680 and same on until 16 channels.
7680*16=122800

I have reshaped the data using

```
np.reshape(data,(7680,16).
```

Now i want each 7680 data points from each channel to split further into 256 data points.
So i am using

```
np.reshape(data,(256,-1,16)
```

Let me know is it a correct approach. Actually i want 0-7680 element in channel one, than 7680-7680*2 in channel 2 and so on.
Now if i take channel one only, it has 7680 points, i want these 7680 points to reshape into 30 trials, such as each trials has 256 elements

Comment: you mean from each channel, change 7680 data points to 256 ones ? any criteria ?

Comment: actually i want to create 2 seconds trials, as sampling frequency is 128Hz, 2*128=256 so splitting data into 2 sec, give me 30 trials

Comment: `reshape` only reshapes elements, does not divide them. so you must ensure that number of your elements remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wrong. When you put you dimensions as `(256,-1,16)`, numpy will do division for you and replace `-1` with `30`. Note that this may only happen for negative integer (I tested with `-1`, `-2`, `-3`). So

```py
np.reshape(data,(256,-1,16))
```

will return an array with size of `256 x 30 x 16` and yes, it's done.

---

EDIT:
for your data, as said:

> First 7680 samples represent 1st channel, then 7680 - 2nd channel, ets.

The correct way to reshape it is

```py
np.reshape(data, (16, 7680))
```

You then want to divide those 7680 samples to 30 trials, each channel contains 256 samples. It's easy:

```py
np.reshape(data, (16, 30, 256))
# or just simply
np.reshape(data, (16, -1, 256)) # as numpy will do division for you
```

If you then want to divide your 256 samples to some cluster of sample, do as the following:

```py
np.reshape(data, (16, 30, number_of_clusters, size_of_each_cluster))
```

Remember to always *go from outside to inside*, place the number of cluster first, then its size.

---

EDIT2: You said you want a set of 30 trials, for each, contains a 2D array that has 16 columns as 16 electrodes and 256 rows as 256 points in 2 seconds.

Here's the code:

```py
temp = np.reshape(data, (7680,16), order='F')
output = temp.reshape((30,256,16))
```

to use 1 line code:

```py
data.reshape((7680,16), order='F').reshape((30,256,16))
```

Explanation: Before python does reshape you array, it first flatten it (if not yet). Then it put each element to a new array one by one.

By default, the `order='C'`, which means it will put elements row by row from top to bottom (same as the way we write and read). While `order='F'` means it will put elements column by column, from left to right.

Your data comes with 7680 points from channel 1 first. That's why I use `order='F'`.

Comment: i am bit confused
`np.reshape(data,(256,-1,16)`
will produce an array of size 256, 30, 16. which result in 122880

The thing that confuses me more, whether shape of data be (256,30,16) or (30,256,16)

Comment: @TalhaAnwar how are the data are collected and arranged ?

Comment: here is data link http://brain.bio.msu.ru/eeg_schizophrenia.htm actually i have not much information.

Comment: i was doing mistake, some things are clear now. I want each trial to have 16 columns, and each columns to have 256 points.

Comment: if we have to do in two steps, such as
`data.reshape(16,7680)`
and then take transpose
and now shape is 
`7680,16`
now i have to reshape it to 30 trials
so now i have to do
`data.reshape(30,256,16)`
Am i correct?

Comment: okay, you should have said that for the first time. since "i dont want data of channels mixed together" did confuse me. Please also edit your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195983/discussion-between-talha-anwar-and-tiendung).